# Show tabbar when new activity starts

Tags: android, android-activity, tabbar

I wrote a simple Android program with 2 tabs. Tab 1 has a button which will open a new window. But I realized that when opening this new window, the Android tab bar will be hidden.

I'd like to always show the Android tab bar when new activity starts ie show tab bar for all activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly, you need to create framelayout, which will host your new activities.

Here is tabs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ScrollView
      android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/bbg">
      <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
         <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"/>
         <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
      </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</TabHost>
```

And here is TabsActivity:

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

      Resources res = getResources(); 
      TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  
      TabHost.TabSpec spec;  
      Intent intent;  
      intent = new Intent().setClass(this, RegistrationActivity.class);
      spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("registration").setIndicator("Регистрация",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_registration))
                        .setContent(intent);
      tabHost.addTab(spec);
      intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LoginActivity.class);
      spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("login").setIndicator("Логин",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_login))
        .setContent(intent);
      tabHost.addTab(spec);
      tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


   }
```

this example will create 2 tabs, and 2 activities. Tap on any tap will start activity. Tabs will be always on top of screen.

UPD.

ActivityGroups may help you
http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/

Comment: In that 2 tabs put one button in one tab and call another activity through intent fun for that button it will open new window without tab bar i need tab bar for that activity also

Comment: @Nanda looks like you need to use ActivityGroups http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/

Comment: Thanks skywa1ker finally i got it

Comment: HI skywa1ker i use this solution in my normal code(Without progress dialog) its function well. but when activity class with progress dialog i get run time exception" android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window " can you help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use THis to start the new Activity

```
View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("tab1", new Intent(this,tab1.class)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
.getDecorView();

setContentView(view);
```

Comment: it shows error in getLocalActivityMangaer() whether it is android default function or user written function if its user written fun pl provide that fun also